# LoadCompleted event in DoWork event

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

First of all, I post my code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    private List<string> list = new List<string>();
    private List<string> arrOfAdresses = new List<string>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        list.Add("http://www.yahoo.com");
        list.Add("http://www.google.com");
    }

    private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("All is done");
    }

    private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (string s in list)
        {
            WebBrowser bro = new WebBrowser();
            bro.Width = bro.Height = 1;
            grid.Children.Add(bro);
            bro.Navigate(s);
            bro.LoadCompleted += OnLoadCompleted;
        }
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void OnLoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser bro = sender as WebBrowser;
        this.arrOfAdresses.Add(bro.Source.ToString()+"Added text");
        MessageBox.Show("xxx"); //MessageBox is ignored
    }

    private void shower_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        arrOfAdresses.Reverse();
        foreach (string s in arrOfAdresses)
            MessageBox.Show(s);
    }
}
```

`button_click` event should store adresses into `arrOfAdresse`, which will be little bit modified.

Next, `shower_Click` should show all modified values which are in `arrOfAdresses`. When I want to show values, which I shoud have in `arrOfAdresses`, it returns me nothing. I think, problem is in `LoadCompleted` event, because when I put the MessageBox the program ignore it. Is there some way I can show values, when `shower_Click` is raised and is there some way I can fix it? Thank you for replies.

Comment: Run it in debug line by line.  Add some try catch.   It may not like creating a UI object in the background.

Comment: Not checking the e.Error property in the RunWorkerCompleted event prevents you from diagnosing the way your DoWork() code crashed.  *Never* skip that check.  You'll then see how your code is violating threading requirements.  So does Debug + Exceptions, Thrown checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

DoWork runs on another thread so you're not allowed to touch the UI (directly). Most obvious offender:

```
  grid.Children.Add(bro);
```

But creating and loading the WebBrowser is probably not OK either.

Most important lesson to learn here:

- always check the `e.Error` property first in a Completed event.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way the message box is just ignored. Most likely the line above it threw an exception. WPF doesn't crash the application when exceptions are thrown, instead he logs them to the Debug output. Look there for the exception and you'll know what's wrong.

Most likely the exception is thrown because the line doesn't occur in the UI thread. If that's the case, all you need to do is run the command using a [dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx), like this:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => arrOfAdresses.Add(bro.Source.ToString() + "Added text")));
```

Note the dispatcher in my sample is a property of window: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.dispatcher(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: When I look into Output of program there is:
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll

Answer (score 0):

I have done things like this in Webbrowser. Loading progress in webbrowser in actually done in a seperate thread even if u call it from the main thread. So in my case, in many situations, if there is any error in between any of the lines in onLoadComplete or onPregress events, the error is not thrown. I donno how or why. But what i'll do is just debug. You have to put breakpoint right into starting line of the onLoadComplete event, and analyse line by line.. Even Try Catch wont give result, but this does.. And at the line where the program skips the next lines will be havin error..

Comment: I see this is not the first time, please publishes only one answer, this is not a forum or chat room. If you think that the answer should be improved or changed, you can always edit it.

Answer (score 0):

There will be an error in the line

```
this.arrOfAdresses.Add(bro.Source.ToString()+"Added text");
```